# Inconsistent Loading JSON and binding to form fields

Tags: php, jquery, json

So I have a datagrid where when a row is clicked a form is loaded, then JSON data is pulled and propagates form fields using JQuery.  It works great...sometimes.  It is very inconsistent, and I can't figure out why it doesn't work every time.  I can click on a row, it loads, then (without refreshing) the next few times it might not, and then (still without refreshing) the next few random number of times it does.

Any help would be appreciated.   The first thing the script does is load the corresponding form into the div #dlg, then pull the JSON data, and then parse and populate the fields.

```
function fw_getFormData(r_id, t_name, r_key){   
    $('#dlg').dialog('refresh', 'dg_process/dg_edit_form.php?table='+t_name),
    jsonURL = 'form_data/dg_forms_data.php?table='+t_name+'&pkey='+r_key+'&id='+r_id;

    var jqxhr = $.getJSON( jsonURL, function() {})

        //JSON load is complete. Propagate form fields.
        .done(function(data) {
            $.each(data, function(index, obj) {  
                $.each(obj, function(key, value) {
                    //$('#'+key).attr("value", value);
                    $("#dlg").parents("div").find('input[name='+key.toLowerCase()+']').val(value);
                 }); //End inner parse of JSON
             }); //End outer Parse
         })  // End .done

        //JSON Did not load
            .fail(function() {
                 alert( "JSON could not load" );
            }) // End .fail
});
```

The JSON it is parsing looks like this:

```
[{"staffID":"1","fname":"Bill","lname":"Smith","email_address":"bsmith@fakeemail.net","password":"testpw"}]
```

As a final note, the alert for .fail never fires when it doesn't work.

Comment: Try alerting something more informative than "JSON could not load", such as the third parameter passed to .fail

Comment: I've added a note to the original post.  The fail alert never fires anyway.

Comment: if the fail alert isn't happening, then you're getting to success.. `console.log(data)` i suspect it isn't what you expect it to be when it fails.

Comment: When I run the console, it's pulling the data and iterating/parsing it each time.  But still the form is blank.  I added: `console.log(key, value);` and it's showing the data.  So something isn't working with connecting the data to the fields in `$("#dlg").parents("div").find('input[name='+key.toLowerCase()+']').val(value);`...but I'm too much of a novice to know what's causing the error.

Comment: Is it some kind of procedural thing?  The #dlg div perhaps not fully loaded so the search for `.parents("div").find` doesn't know find what it needs to propagate/bind?  But then would the form even show?

Comment: actually, yes that's the entire problem. the dialog i sometimes done loading, and other times isn't. That would explain why it inconsistently works/doesn't work. There most be a done loading event with the dialog you can listen to.